# Ошибка при обучении модели классификации текста

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ml.net

Хочу создать модель с использованием ML.Net машинного обучения на классификацию текста, но при попытке обучить модель получаю сообщение

> Соединение JSON-RPC с удаленной стороной было утрачено до того, как удалось выполнить запрос.

[Скрин ошибки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCLkA.png)

Как исправить эту проблему?

Пытался менять тип обучения модели, спрашивал у Chat GPT, но я так понял что ошибка состоит в запросе к серверу? Что может пойти не так - без понятия

Comment: Текстовую информацию стоит вставить текстом в вопрос.

Comment: Этот вопрос лучше задать Microsoft, ибо только они могут сказать что не так с их собственной программой. ИМХО, билдер ML очень сырой и кривой на данный момент, лучше осваивать саму библиотеку и пытаться написать все самостоятельно. Ну а ошибка, она может из-за чего угодно, от старой версии студии и билдера, кривой установки, до размера датасета.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, наверное, так и сделаю. Я думал, может это у меня какие-то траблы, что-то недонастроил, но как я понял, всё же ошибка и правда не моя, а Microsoft) 
Не думаю, что дело в данных. Их не много, и ложатся они корректно (по столбцам ложатся правильно). 
Видел что везде в виде-уроках руками всё прописывают. Наверное, так и попробую.. В любом случае - спасибо за ответ )